# JPQL Constructor ignoring Rows whose have a NULL value

Tags: java, sql, spring, constructor, jpql

I have following statement:

```
@Query("SELECT "
        + "new com.app.model.RestaurantOrderPartial( "
            + "o.orderId, o.orderedAt, o.orderType, o.orderState, o.orderValue, o.deliveryPrice, o.deliveredBy, o.driver) "
        + "FROM Order o "
        + "WHERE o.restaurant.restaurantId = ?1 "
        + "AND o.orderedAt BETWEEN ?2 and ?3 "
        + "ORDER BY o.orderedAt DESC ")
List<RestaurantOrderPartial> getRestaurantOrdersCompressed(long restaurantId, LocalDateTime dateBeforePeriod, LocalDateTime now); //12 Month
```

The rows in table where `o.driver` is `NULL`, the constructor doesn´t contruct the entry to an object and **doesn´t include it** in the result list.

Why does it have this behavior? and how let the constructor include the entries where Driver is null, in the custom object `RestaurantOrderPartial` the Driver object would be null according to value in Column.

Here are my POJOs:

```
public class RestaurantOrderPartial {
    
    private long orderId;
    private LocalDateTime orderedAt;
    private OrderType orderType;
    private OrderState orderState;
    private Long orderValue;
    
    
    private int deliveryPrice;
    private DeliveredBy deliveredBy;
    private Driver driver;

}
```

---

```
public class Driver {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long driverId;

@Column
private String email;

@Column
private String password;

@Column
private String fullName;

@Column
private String phoneNumber;

@Column
private String secondaryPhoneNumber;

@Column
private String fullAddress;

@Column
private boolean isActive;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "cityId")    
private City city;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "locationId")
private Location location;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="driver")
private List<Order> orders;
```

---

Sample Data:
[image: sample data]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is restaurantId and oderedAt set if driver is null?

Comment: yes. everything is set except o.driver. Driver (id in column which references to an Driver in an appropriate table) is null.

Comment: can you show the class and sample data please

Comment: Kindly see my updated Question

Comment: Did you run the hibernate generated query against the database to ensure that returned data contains the rows with driver value `null` to rule out any data setup issue?

Comment: Tested. Query against the Database returns the data correctly. So it seems to be an JPQL issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want o.driver to be fetched if it is null, you must specify a left outer join; o.driver is always an inner join and so filters out null values from the results.

Try something more like

```
"SELECT "
        + "new com.app.model.RestaurantOrderPartial( "
            + "o.orderId, o.orderedAt, o.orderType, o.orderState, o.orderValue, o.deliveryPrice, o.deliveredBy, driver) "
        + "FROM Order o LEFT OUTER JOIN o.driver driver"
        + "WHERE o.restaurant.restaurantId = ?1 "
        + "AND o.orderedAt BETWEEN ?2 and ?3 "
        + "ORDER BY o.orderedAt DESC ")
```